# t:commandSortHeader not being styled

Tags: java, jsf, tomahawk

I've got the following JSF:

```
<t:column styleClass="cb-status-column">
    <f:facet name="header"> 
        <t:commandSortHeader columnName="externalStatus" styleClass="cb-status-column">
            Status
        </t:commandSortHeader>
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{tx.externalStatus}" title="#{tx.externalStatus}"/>
</t:column>
```

Unfortunately, it renders like this:

```
<th>
  <a href="#" onclick="return oamSubmitForm('transactionsTableForm','cb-activity-table:j_id131');" id="cb-activity-table:j_id131">
    Status
  </a>
</th>
```

How do I get it to look like this:

```
<th class="cb-status-column">
  <a href="#" onclick="return oamSubmitForm('transactionsTableForm','cb-activity-table:j_id131');" id="cb-activity-table:j_id131">
    Status
  </a>
</th>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
<t:column styleClass="cb-status-column" headerstyleClass="cb-status-column">
```

?

Comment: Same results as the middle above.